# ora-01747: user.table.column, table.column or column description is invalid

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

everyone.

I created a table in oracle with a sde.st_geometry column. I followed the instructions of ArcGIS help to register the table into geodatabase. However, when I try to load data into this table, I got this error:

```
ora-01747: user.table.column, table.column or column description is invalid
```

My table creation statement is:

```
create table tbl_Comm_Cove 
(
ID                   NUMBER(10,0)         not null,
Name                 CHAR(200),
Devi_Num             CHAR(8),
Code                 CHAR(200),
Unit_Grid            CHAR(10),
GID                  CHAR(200),
Belo_Road            CHAR(200),
Inst_Time            DATE,
Mana_Depa_ID         NUMBER(10,0),
Owne_Depa            CHAR(200),
Main_Depa            CHAR(200),
Mate_ID              NUMBER(10,0),
Diam                 NUMBER(10,2),
Devi_Stat_ID         NUMBER(10,0),
"Desc"               CHAR(200),
Shap_ID              NUMBER(10,0),
Init_Time            DATE,
Chan_Time            DATE,
Note                 CLOB,
constraint PK_TBL_COMM_COVE primary key (ID)
);
/
alter table tbl_comm_cove add loc sde.st_geometry;
/
CREATE INDEX tbl_comm_cove_idx ON tbl_comm_cove(loc)
INDEXTYPE IS sde.st_spatial_index
PARAMETERS('st_grids=1,3,0 st_srid=0');
/
```

The id is self—incremental.
My oracle version is 11.2.0, and ArcSDE version is 10.0

What should I do?

Comment: It's unclear from your description what command or operation generated the error message.  It's probably pretty important to know which service pack of 10.0 you have installed, and what exact command you used to register the table (less password, of course).  As a rule, it's unwise to build the spatial index before loading, though dropping it after registration is fine.

Comment: I'm trying to "load data" from another .mdb file using ArcCatalog. Where can I see which service pack I installed?

Comment: The Service Packs page has a link to PatchFinder.exe.